# How do twitter4j Paging pages work?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I'm working on writing a simple program to fetch tweets for an information retrieval class (later I will be learning to index and search through them). For now, I just want to gather data. I'm using the twitter4j API and am having trouble understanding the Paging class and how it works. Below is a snippet of code:

```
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()); 
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    Paging paging = new Paging(2,40);
    try{
        List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline("google", paging);

        System.out.println(paging);
        for(Status status : statuses)
        {
            System.out.println(status.getText());
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n\n");
        paging.setPage(2);
        statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline("google",paging);

        for(Status status : statuses)
        {
            System.out.println(status.getText());
        }
    }
    catch(TwitterException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My hope was that the second call to `twitter.getUserTimeline` would return the next 40 tweets from Google as [this example](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/148/how-to-get-more-than-20-results-from-a-user-timeline-with-twitter4j) seems to suggest, but upon inspection, both return the same 40 tweets. Can someone then explain what the Paging class actually does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first call should request the first page `Paging paging = new Paging(1, 40);`, not the second one.